# How do I display HashMap and List property in Jasper

Tags: jasper-reports

Hello All 
I have a POJO class which have some property out of them two are of type

List someName;
TreeMap> myMap;

here I am getting this data from the above property and I would Like to show them on jasper report. I want to know what to write on jrxml file, I am using jasper version 1.0.2
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can easily display the values on a list or map using JasperReports directly from a POJO.

I believe you would have to wrap the POJO in a bean data source. See also:

- http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRAbstractBeanDataSource.html
- http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRBeanCollectionDataSource.html

Then, you "connect" to the bean data source and return the results as required.

This probably requires JasperReports version 3.0 or greater.